# Bootstrap page layout issue in using Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap columns for styling my page. I have 4 main div in my `row` and I expect them to display in a row but they aren't and also a scroll-bar are inserted in the bottom of the page. what is the problem? My codes and JsFiddle are the following.

HTML:

```
<div id="pre-footer" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="adv-clickable col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <a href="#"><p>fdhgf</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fdgdfg</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fgdfg</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fgdfg fgdfg</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fgdfg gfddg</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>dgdfgfd</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fgdfgdf fgdff gdfgdfg dgdfg</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="adv-clickable col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <a href="#"><p>fdhgf</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fdgdfg</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fgdfg</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fgdfg fgdfg</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fgdfg gfddg</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>dgdfgfd</p></a>
                <a href="#"><p>fgdfgdf fgdff gdfgdfg dgdfg</p></a>
            </div>
            <div id="pre-footer-nested1" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <img src="images/pre-footer-logo.png">
                <div id="socials" class="col-xs-9 center-block">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-linkedin-square"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-telegram"></i></a>
                </div>
                <form action="#" class="form-group col-xs-9 center-block">
                    <label for="email" class="text-center">ghdfgfdghfghfghfg</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="fdgdfgfdhggfh" >
                    <input type="submit" value="dfghfdghgfhg" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="pre-footer-nested2" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <img src="images/nemad.jpg" >
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="footer-logos">

                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-logos">

                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-logos">

                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-logos">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
#pre-footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.adv-clickable{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.adv-clickable a:first-child p{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.adv-clickable p{
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.adv-clickable a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#pre-footer-nested1{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 img{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#pre-footer-nested2{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
#socials{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#socials i{
    color: #01a89e;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 form{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 form label{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 input:last-child{
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #01a89e;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#pre-footer-nested1 input:last-child:active{
    background-color: #0f8079;
}
#pre-footer-nested2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#pre-footer-nested2 img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
}
#pre-footer-nested2 div{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 22px;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Here is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzsseLef/)

Comment: Just a tip: directly nesting columns (as you've done with `.col-md-9>.col-md-3`) can do weird things in bootstrap. Try to alternate columns and rows ([reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting))

Comment: @wilusdaman I've tested that before and remove `div class="col-md-9"` but no difference!

Comment: which bootstrap version are you use in your project?

Comment: why u use display:flex every col ? simply just remove it, take container after body tag this will fix your scroll issue and lastly remove offset classes from col make offset 0 till your desire breakpoint so u will get result that u want. here is the simple demo https://jsfiddle.net/fzsseLef/3/

Comment: @AwesomeDesigner Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: @soheil  then why are you use flex box. you can simply use bootstrap grid system for get your content in row.

Comment: @AwesomeDesigner I use `flexbox` for aligning items vertically and horizontally. Is it wrong?

Comment: @soheil  its not wrong but if you want align vertical and horizontal then use display table.flex box conflict with bootstrap v3.*.*. and if you want to use flexbox then use bootstrap new version https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @AwesomeDesigner Thanks, Bro

Comment: most well come @soheil